# GXT 3 \ Grid \ Width of the first column

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have problem when using GXT. The width of the first column of Grid is adjusted automatically (or set 500px). How to fix it?

This construction:

```
    ColumnConfig<M, N> firstColumn;
    //some code
    firstColumn.setWidth(width);
```

does not works, but width of other columns is set correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have forceFit or autofill turned on? Both of those will have an effect where columns are sized to fit the available space.

Do you have a autoExpandColumn? That resizes whichever column is set to use the rest of the space.

Several of the GXT Grid examples set the first column to be autoexpand, so if you copied from there, you might still have this turned on.

Comment: forceFit and autoFill is false. 
Did you mean autoExpandColumn or autoFillColumn?

Comment: Sorry yes, autoExpandColumn, there is no such property as autoFillColumn. I've updated the answer to reflect this.